# Show full file name in title bar in MacOS Ventura Finder

Tags: finder, menu-bar, ventura

everybody!

I actually run MacOS Ventura (last update) and I would like to always display full file name (not file path) in the title bar of the Finder.

In the new OS, the filename is often truncated to display toolbar buttons. To display it and the dropdown arrow for moving the file location, it is necessary to roll on the file name. This is really annoying to me.

I found how to show always the file icon in the title bar (useful for dragging) but can't find how to make the filename fully be shown in the title bar.

It is not a problem if the toolbar displays under title bar with filename like it was a long time ago :)

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you!